C# identity conversion and value representation
I can't wrap my head around identity conversion in a context of preserving the representation of a value with this example provided in "C# in Depth" book:
public delegate void PrintString(string value); // or any other reference type

public static void PrintAnything(object value)
{
   Console.WriteLine(value);
}

PrintString ps = PrintAnything;

So, string (or any other reference type) to object conversion doesn't change representation of the original, but what "doesn't change representation" actually means? And how does boxing changes the representation of a value type (i do understand that it implies a creation of an object and copying data from value type), maybe a more formal explanation of a representation will answer the second part of the question.

This question is similar to: What exactly is the Identity Conversion in C#?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@sous2817, I checked it beforehand and no, it doesn't say anything about representation in context of identity conversion, it mentions only explicit\implicit conversion from type to itself and object-dynamic which is maybe a related thing, but not exactly a situation i mention here. Maybe I should rename the title to something like: "Identity Conversion and Object Representation"?

Your example of assigning a delegate is a variance question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/using-variance-in-delegates not a boxing question. Specifically Contravariance, as all strings are objects, PrintAnything can accept any string arguments.

This example is provided in the chapter that is dedicated to C# 2 and goes like "will always be given a string reference, and that’s convertible to an object reference via an identity conversion.". I am aware of variance, but the mention of identity conversion made me confused.

References are pretty much just pointers. Addresses to pieces of memory. And what exactly is that in a computer? It is a number of fixed size. How exactly these are represented is an implementation detail, but anyway it is guaranteed that all objects have the same representation.
One possible implementation, on 64-bit machine is to implement them as... 64-bit number. So when you pass around objects, you actually pass 64-bit number, regardless of what that object is, in particular how many fields it has, or whether it is an array, or something else. When you want to get to a field, you take this 64-bit address and read memory from that address (potentially with field's offset). That's pretty much how every modern language over modern cpu works.
So as you can see, it is trivial to cast any reference type to Object. You literally just do nothing, these already are objects. These already are 64-bit numbers. It's just that refering to it as Object you no longer have a way to access its fields or methods. I will even make a risky simplification here: class definition is pretty much just a sequence of offsets, meaning "this field is of size X and starts at offset Y from the beginning of the object". That's all the information you need to read/write field value from object's address. It is a simplification of course, because we have inheritance and virtual methods, which make things more complicated. But only slightly, and it is a story for another time.
On the other hand, C# also has structs. These are different beasts. These are not addresses, but actual values, and can be of any size. So for example bool is a struct of 1 byte (8 bits), while int is of 4 bytes (32 bits). You can also declare your own structs, of any size.
When those are being passed around, they are not actually passed as addresses, but as concrete values. So a function accepting an int of size 32 bits, cannot be converted to a delegate that accepts Object, which is a reference, which has size 64 (at least on 64-bit machine). There are low level technical reasons why this cannot be done. And even if those sizes matches by chance, reading from a struct is not like reading from object.
When you call a function, the compiler will generate code that moves around this struct, sometimes in registers, sometimes on stack. A.k.a. calling conventions, which is a complicated low level detail that heavily depends on cpu, operating system and the (jit) compiler. And then reading from a struct may not involve reading from memory at all, the data may already be in a cpu register.
For those low level, technical reasons structs and classes are different things. They have to be. It is precisely why C# has structs, so that those low level optimizations can be performed. Managed objects are simply slower to access, move around, (de)allocate, etc. But are easier to work with. Pros and cons, as always.

And how does boxing changes the representation of a value type

Boxing is a process of allocating memory, copying the struct data into the newly allocated memory and work with this memory. In a managed way. So now you take this say 32-bit int, you allocate 32-bits of memory for it, move the data there. What you get in return is a 64-bit number, address, and now you work with this address. So the size of address will always be the same (again: that's why conversion between classes is trivial and safe as long as you cast in inheritance hierarchy). While the size of underlying data varies.
But if you change PrintAnything to say PrintAnything(int value) then the assignment will be invalid. C# won't automatically change the parameter to boxed version. Because boxed value is a class, not a struct. And so C# would have to generate a new function, with new signature for you. And recompile it, since as I said, accessing struct is different then accessing objects. All of that implicitly. And C# developers decided that it should not do that. Which is an interesting question on its own I guess.
